# Starting a program with MSBuild/Web Deployment Project and not waiting for it

Tags: msbuild

I would like explorer opened up on a certain folder, after the deployment has happened, and I'm using the following to attemp it:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="..."></Exec>
</Target>
```

However, a simple "explorer \somewhere" causes the build process to block on explorer, and it wont finish until you close explorer. Prefixing it with `start explorer \\somewhere` doesn't change that either.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thing is that we only deploy to a intermediate stage, and want the last step done manually, and opening an explorer on the relevant folder is a nicety. The Exec command actually calls a BAT file if that matters, using VS.NET 2008, on Server 2008 Standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up doing was have a

```
<Exec Command="..." Timeout="2000"></Exec>
```

That is, launch Explorer from a different Exec element then the copy-element, and then add a somewhat short timeout on this element. This means VS starts up Explorer, and after 2 seconds, returns.

Comment: You should also set ContinueOnError="true" if you don't want it to error after the timeout.

Comment: this will kill the process if not finished within timeout

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was starting a powershell process to the pre-build events. It executes the command without blocking the rest of the build process.

```
powershell start-process -workingdirectory "..." "cmd " """/k ..."""
```

Answer (score -1):

In the DOS shell you can use cmd /c  to call another process and not wait for it's return.  You this works fine as a post-build event.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="cmd /c start explorer"></Exec>
</Target>
```

Comment: Well, tried CMD /C, makes no difference it seems. Firing up cscript and using WScript.shell's "run" is no-go as well.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your reply CptSkippy. Anyway, it runs, but doesn't return. IE, VS is blocked by the waiting Explorer window.

Comment: @MyItchyChin Actually I was talking about Svend's first comment: this does not seem to work, even though it looks like it should. I certainly was not able to get it to work!

Comment: @Kazark Just a gentle note; it's better to try to inquire about an answer not working a bit more... gently. Often there's a little error that can be fixed, or some minor misunderstanding or the like. An answer does not necessarily need to be deleted.