# How to escape quote marks in Exec Command in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to build an MSBuild script that maps a network drive to a drive letter in the script, but unfortunately the path to the target folder includes an embedded space.  The embedded space causes the mapping to fail, and I don't know if it is possible to escape quotes around the path.  I've tried double quote marks, but MSBuild doesn't like it (either that or Windows XP doesn't like it).  Anyone know how to code this beast so the map works?

```
<Exec Command="net use x: \\ofmapoly703\c$\program files\ar\iap /user:$(UserID) $(Password)"
WorkingDirectory="c:\"
ContinueOnError="false"
/>
```

The embedded space of course occurs in "program files".

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Use [`&quot;`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping) to encode the double quotes that you want `net` to see inside the `Command` attribute value :

```
<Exec Command="net use x: &quot;\\ofmapoly703\c$\program files\ar\iap&quot; /user:$(UserID) $(Password)" 
WorkingDirectory="c:\" 
ContinueOnError="false" 
/>
```

Comment: This does not help when you have `Command="quot;$(PathWithTrailingBackslash)&quot;"`
because it renders as `"Path\With\Trailing\Backslash\"` and the `\"` is the command-line escape sequence for `"`, so all following arguments get messed up.

Comment: @jnm2 Couldn't you just add another `&quot;` after the second one? `Command="quot;$(PathWithTrailingBackslash)&quot;&quot;"`

Comment: @TetraDev Then the backslash is still missing and you have an unclosed quote, the effect of which I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 100):

You can use single quotes for command ,e.g.

```
  <Exec Command='explorer.exe "$(DestinationDir)"' IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

(From [MSBuild exec task without blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387456/msbuild-exec-task-without-blocking/6528765#6528765))

Comment: For me the use single quotes instead of &quot; it's a better solution. Because the &quot;. That could lead to problems when you try to do a XmlPoke, its going to space characters in a funny way: from &quot; to &amp;quot;

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quotation marks - instead of `"foo bar baz"`, use `%22foo bar baz%22`.

The hex value of `"` is 22.

References

- [Escape special characters in MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-msbuild?view=vs-2022)
- [MSBuild special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 0):

As detailed by @Michael-Freidgeim the solution to this is to single quote, however you still have issue with trailing slashes (in Paths) being treated as escape characters in certain circumstances, a good method to avoid that would be to follow any folder paths with a dot (.)