# How to launch a program but not wait for it to exit in msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, code-coverage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSBuild exec task without blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387456/msbuild-exec-task-without-blocking)

In MSBuild I need to launch a process (vsperfcmd) but not wait around for it to finish since it blocks indefinitely until a shutdown command is called from elsewhere. I'm currently launching it with the `exec` task:

```
<exec command="vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:test.coverage" />
```

I've tried using "start" but I get the same blocking issue

```
<exec command="start vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:test.coverage" />
```

Strangely the same command does not block if entered at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try putting the command in a DOS batch file and invoking the batch file instead. Not very elegant but might do the trick. If that doesn't work then call a batch file which calls another to do the work. e.g.

mycommand1.bat:

```
mycommand2.bat
```

mycommand2.bat:

```
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:test.coverage
```

mycommand1 will NOT wait for the mycommand2 to complete before continuing (unless you used CALL mycommand2).

Comment: sadly this doesn't work, even with two layers of batch file.

Comment: You could also try creating a custom build task (LaunchWithoutWait) in c# (or your preferred .NET language) which just runs the process without waiting.

Comment: yes, that's my next plan

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in your exec task, which runs explorer and then returns immediately,

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <Message Text="Before" />
  <Exec Command="start $(COMSPEC) /k &quot;$(WINDIR)\explorer.exe &amp; exit&quot;" />
  <Message Text="After" />
</Target>
```

Since the command you are executing has arguments, you may need to experiment with getting that command properly enclosed in quotes.  Take a look at the "help cmd" /S option.