# .NET Standard 2.0 library reduce output/build assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0). Several other assemblies reference this library.

When I build this assembly I just see in e.g. bin\Release\netstandard2.0 my library.dll, a .pdb, .deps.json and a Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd.

Only 4 files in there.

However when I look in my other projects bin\Release or bin\Debug folders (which are just WPF projects or normal Class Libraries) I see a huge list of System.*.dll libraries.

After changing my Visual Studio 2017 options to:

> [Tools] --> [Options] --> [Projects and Solutions] --> [Build and Run]
>   --> [MSBuild project build output verbosity:] --> Diagnostic

I've seen this list:

```
>Added Item(s): 
2>    _NETStandardLibraryNETFrameworkLib=
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netfx.force.conflicts.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\netstandard.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.AppContext.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Collections.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Collections.Specialized.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ComponentModel.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Console.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Data.Common.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Globalization.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Compression.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.FileSystem.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.Pipes.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Linq.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Linq.Expressions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Linq.Parallel.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Linq.Queryable.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Http.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.NameResolution.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Ping.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Requests.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Security.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.Sockets.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Net.WebSockets.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.ObjectModel.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Reflection.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Resources.Reader.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Resources.Writer.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Handles.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Claims.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.Principal.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Security.SecureString.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Text.Encoding.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Thread.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Threading.Timer.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.XDocument.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.XPath.dll
2>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
```

Now I know that it actually comes from my .NET Standard 2.0 library as these are the assemblies that are actually in my other projects bin\Debug and bin\Release folders where the .NET Standard 2.0 library was referenced.

In Visual Studio 2017 in Solution Explorer I've made all files visible by clicking [Show All Files]. There I've found a *project.assets.json* file in my .NET Standard 2.0 library. And I now see that my library is indeed the source of evil:

```
  "NETStandard.Library/2.0.0": {
      "sha512": "<removed :-)>",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "netstandard.library/2.0.0",
      "files": [
        "LICENSE.TXT",
        "THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.TXT",
        "build/NETStandard.Library.targets",
        "build/netstandard2.0/NETStandard.Library.targets",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.AppContext.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Collections.Specialized.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Collections.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ComponentModel.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Console.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Core.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Data.Common.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Data.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Drawing.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Globalization.Calendars.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Globalization.Extensions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Globalization.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.Compression.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.FileSystem.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.Pipes.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.IO.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Linq.Expressions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Linq.Parallel.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Linq.Queryable.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Linq.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Http.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.NameResolution.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Ping.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Requests.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Security.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.Sockets.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.WebSockets.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Net.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Numerics.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ObjectModel.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Reflection.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Resources.Reader.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Resources.Writer.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Handles.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Runtime.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Claims.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.Principal.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Security.SecureString.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Text.Encoding.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.Overlapped.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.Tasks.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.Thread.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.Timer.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Threading.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Transactions.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.ValueTuple.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Web.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Windows.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.Linq.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.Serialization.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.XDocument.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.XPath.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.Xml.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/System.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/mscorlib.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/netstandard.dll",
        "build/netstandard2.0/ref/netstandard.xml",
        "lib/netstandard1.0/_._",
        "netstandard.library.2.0.0.nupkg.sha512",
        "netstandard.library.nuspec"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Why are all these System.*.dll assemblies outputted?

**How do I reduce these assemblies in my bin\Release bin\Debug?**

My WPF application and normal Class library target the .NET Framework, so these file are available, but still they are included in my bin\Debug bin\Release folders.
How can this be reduced?

Now I have to add every single additional System.*.dll in my Wix Setup..., without it the application directly crashes, while it runs on a PC with Full .NET Framework installed.)

**Update:**

Looks like it is a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/415

Comment: Project and settings files in VS are notoriously bad at cleaning up unrequired resources.  If you know for a fact you don't need them then remove the references manually from both the project and *any* settings files.  It may turn out that you have a dependency that you've not accounted for, but it sounds like you're pretty sure they're just not needed.  Blame Visual Studio, fix it, move on ;)

Comment: when not adding them in my Wix setup, the application crashes, so they seem to be needed...

Comment: So what's the question then?  I'm a bit lost if you need them then you can't remove them - the end.

Comment: Just found something. Looks like it is a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/415

Comment: Bolting netstandard onto .NET 4.6.1 was pretty doggone ugly.  It was just slow to catch up, 4.7.1 is a lot better.

Comment: I've changed to 4.7.1 and it is better, but still too much assemblies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my .NET Standard NuGet package trigger so many dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365136/why-does-my-net-standard-nuget-package-trigger-so-many-dependencies)

Comment: This is expected behavior and a duplicate of the question I linked above. Only in upcoming .NET 4.7.2 it is expected that no additional dlls will be added to the build.

Comment: oh boy @MartinUllrich that is annoying...will wait untill we can switch to  4.7.2...

Comment: But they don't cause any problems. just some files..

Comment: they cause additional lines in installer, more difficulties to debug incorrect setup files etc