# Visual Studio 2017 - Potentially unneeded dlls in release folder

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to obtain an executable file with only the necessary dlls in the release folder, unfortunately VS is putting in that folder even System dlls, that afaik are not supposed to be redistributed with the executable.
I'd like to know if there's a way to make VS add to the release folder only dlls the executable can not work without, the ones that are supposed to be redistributed.

Thank you.
Release folder:
[image: Release folder]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: These are not 'system' assemblies that are in the GAC. These are assemblies included with .NET Standard NuGet packages that you either reference directly or are dependencies of the packages or the framework you reference. They are required for your application to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These assemblies are shims for .Net Standard where the full framework had gaps. Based on the assemblies in that folder, I assume that your exe is targeting .net 4.6.x and you are consuming a .net standard library.

If you upgrade to .net 4.7.2 you will see the number of required `System.*` assemblies reduced greatly.

See this answer for more details: [Why does my .NET Standard NuGet package trigger so many dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365136/why-does-my-net-standard-nuget-package-trigger-so-many-dependencies/47366401#47366401)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a dotnet core project. Use the "dotnet publish" command to create your deployment files (the screenshot looks like a VS build directory?). You might see more dlls than you're used too if you're coming to dotnet core from using the Windows frameworks previously, but it depends on the publish options you use.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish