# Visual Studio 2017 project output contains random unreferenced system DLL files

Tags: c#, monogame

My references:

- Monogame Framework
- Monogame Extended (4 libraries)
- Newtonsoft.Json
- System
- System.xml

When I compile, I get a folder filled with arbitrary system DLLs (for example: System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll, System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll) in the debug/release folder.

I made a new blank project of the same template and added the exact same references, compiled, and got no random DLLs.

When I delete the unnecessary files, everything still works normally. 
Also I tried deleting the 'obj' folder and recompiling but it still creates these files.

Comment: Are you targeting .Net Standard?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365136/why-does-my-net-standard-nuget-package-trigger-so-many-dependencies

Comment: @amy this is the appropriate duplicate i feel, nice find

Comment: That was it thanks. I was targeting 4.6.1 but I switched it to 4.7.2 and it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are likely 2 causes.

1. Make sure you don't have references to them.
2. You are using dependencies that are using dependencies. This is what happens.

The solve

1. Use a dependency walker, and find out who is referencing them
2. and/or use resharper to identify dependencies that aren't needed and remove them

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I dont have references to them, and these dependencies dont have references to them either as far as I know. 

I will try those suggestions